# How to expose a native dll on EC2 or Azure?

Tags: web-services, azure, dll, amazon-ec2, native-code

I have a native C++ dll doing some advanced calculations which should be kept secret. The dll has an interface, let's say:

```
int calculate(int* params, int params_length);
```

I want to expose this dll to web applications. So far I found that common solution is to build a web service around the dll (SOAP or REST).

What is the best way of solving this kind of a problem, what platform to use (EC2 or Azure) ? I would prefer to not use .NET solution.

Comment: This depends on how you prefer to consume that function. Will the consumer be on the same machine or elsewhere? Which is the consumer platform?

Comment: The consumer will be independent web application running on a completely different server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a service around it will be best solution. REST service if preferable as performs better and we don't need to build SOAP wrapper anymore.

Also, if the web applications are written in .NET you can directly use C++ DLL, as explained here,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/02/780637.aspx

Regarding platform, there is no best platform as such and you can use any of the two. However, if you are building solutions in .NET and using Visual Studio then Azure will be preferred as there is built-in tooling in Visual Studio for Azure.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to build the service around my dll. .NET would be one possibility, gSOAP library for C++ would probably the the job too. Maybe CGI is an alternative as well ?

Comment: @tommyk You start with a "ASP.NET Web API" project template and work from there. This way you save a lot of effort on wiring all the stuff together.